# Trying to Load an Image with Dialogue Box in Python and Display it in a Layer - PYTHON 3.4 using Tkinter and PIL

Tags: python

I am trying to Make a simple Photo editor. I already got all the functions for editing photos. Just trying to make it look nice with a GUI. When the user presses file>open, the open dialogue box comes up and they can choose an image. Then I want that image to load inside of a Layer in the GUI.

Here is my code so far:
p.s. When I put the code that is inside the open_img function outise the function, it works, but when i put it inside the function, no image loads

```
import os
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename


def g_quit():
    mExit=tkinter.messagebox.askyesno(title="Quit", message="Are You Sure?")
    if mExit>0:
        mGui.destroy()
        return

#open menu
def open_img():
    file = tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir='D:/Users/')
    w_box = 500
    h_box = 500

    pil_image = Image.open(file)

    w, h = pil_image.size

    pil_image_resized = resize(w, h, w_box, h_box, pil_image)
    # wr, hr = pil_image_resized.size

    tk_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(pil_image_resized)

    label2.config(image=tk_image, width=w_box, height=h_box)

def resize(w, h, w_box, h_box, pil_image):
    '''
    resize a pil_image object so it will fit into
    a box of size w_box times h_box, but retain aspect ratio
    '''
    f1 = 1.0*w_box/w  # 1.0 forces float division in Python2
    f2 = 1.0*h_box/h
    factor = min([f1, f2])
    #print(f1, f2, factor)  # test
    # use best down-sizing filter
    width = int(w*factor)
    height = int(h*factor)
    return pil_image.resize((width, height), Image.ANTIALIAS)



mGui = Tk()
mGui.title('Photo Filters')
mGui.geometry('650x500')
mGui.resizable(0, 0) #Disable Resizeability
photoFrame = Frame(mGui, bg="orange", width=500, height=500)
photoFrame.pack(side=LEFT)
filtersFrame = Frame(mGui, bg="yellow", width=150, height=500)
filtersFrame.pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y)
label2 = Label(photoFrame)

#Create Buttons for All the Possible Filters
negative_btn = Button(filtersFrame, text="Negative")
negative_btn.pack()

weighted_grayscale_btn = Button(filtersFrame, text="weighted Grayscale")
weighted_grayscale_btn.pack()

solarize_btn = Button(filtersFrame, text="Solarize")
solarize_btn.pack()

black_and_white_btn = Button(filtersFrame, text="Black and White")
black_and_white_btn.pack()

black_and_white_and_gray_btn = Button(filtersFrame, text="Black and White and Gray")
black_and_white_and_gray_btn.pack()

extreme_contrast_btn = Button(filtersFrame, text="Extreme Contrast")
extreme_contrast_btn.pack()

sepia_tint_btn = Button(filtersFrame, text="Sepia Tint")
sepia_tint_btn.pack()

adjust_component_btn = Button(filtersFrame, text="Adjusts Components")
adjust_component_btn.pack()

posterize_btn = Button(filtersFrame, text="Posterize")
posterize_btn.pack()

simplify_btn = Button(filtersFrame, text="Simplify")
simplify_btn.pack()

detect_edges_btn = Button(filtersFrame, text="Detect Edges")
detect_edges_btn.pack()

detect_edges_better_btn = Button(filtersFrame, text="Detect Edges Better")
detect_edges_better_btn.pack()

blur_btn = Button(filtersFrame, text="Blur")
blur_btn.pack()

flip_image = Button(filtersFrame, text="Flip Horizontal")
flip_image.pack()



#Menu Bar
menubar = Menu(mGui)
filemenu = Menu(menubar)
#Create the Menu Options that go under drop down
filemenu.add_command(label="New")
filemenu.add_command(label="Open", command=open_img)
filemenu.add_command(label="Save As")
filemenu.add_command(label="Close", command=g_quit)
#Create the Main Button (e.g file) which contains the drop down options
menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)
mGui.config(menu=menubar)
mGui.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You've actually got two problems here. One of them, you found for yourself—you never call `label2.pack()`, so the label itself never gets displayed. But, even after you fix that, the label is blank.

As the [`Label`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/label.htm) documentation says:

> You can use the label to display `PhotoImage` and `BitmapImage` objects. When doing this, make sure you keep a reference to the image object, to prevent it from being garbage collected by Python’s memory allocator.

You're not doing that. You store the `PhotoImage` in a local variable, `tk_image`, which goes away as soon as the function exits.

That should explain why it works if you move the code outside a function. If you do that, `tk_image` becomes a global variable, which doesn't go away until the whole program exits. And, since you're already using global variables all over the place implicitly, one possible fix is to use an explicit global for this:

```
def open_img():
    global tk_image
    # the rest of your code
```

However, a much better trick is to just cram the image into an attribute of something else that's going to stick around, like the `Label` object itself:

```
def open_img():
    # your existing code
    label2.tk_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(pil_image_resized)
    label2.config(image=label2.tk_image, width=w_box, height=h_box)
```

Now, the image can't be garbage collected until the label that's using it gets garbage collected (or until you replace it with a new image).

In fact, now that I look at the docs, this is exactly what the example of using a `PhotoImage` with a `Label` does:

```
photo = PhotoImage(file="icon.gif")
w = Label(parent, image=photo)
w.photo = photo
w.pack()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It Worked perfectly fine. Just realized I also forgot to pack label2. But this solution really worked. Again, thanks a lot

Comment: @Arun: Ah, I didn't notice that you forgot the `pack` also. So not only was the label empty, it was also invisible. :) Good catch.